# Cannot download apps from AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-appstore

[English is not my mother language]

I cannot download any app from AppStore(it shows the downloading process in AppStore and it shows the icon of the app in setting>General>usage) but I can't find it on the home screen and I cannot open it through AppStore. Does anyone know how to fix it?

My iPhone is:
iPhone 4s
iOS 7.1

Comment: what app is it you are having trouble with

Comment: I cannot download any apps. :(

Comment: where do your downloads go normally

Comment: To the home page!

Comment: open your finder and look for the file  by name, you should see a progress bar for the download under the size for the file.

Comment: I know that, thanks, but I am unable to open the app, I can see it in setting

Comment: Let me get that, you have downloaded the app but now it wont open when you click on it?, so it is not that you can not download problem then!! so what does it do when xyou click on it? again what app is it specificaly please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a soft-reset on the device. Settings/General/Reset/Reset All Settings and try again. No data will be lost (other than passwords).